# Self-adjoint operators $TT^*$ and $T^*T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, inner-products

Let $T$ be some operator in Euclidean or Unitary space.
How can I prove that the operators $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ are self-adjoint and have the same eigenvalues?
Im confused.. Where do I begin?
Is this possible when T is a normal operator?

Comment: Some hints: For self-adjointness, you need to prove that your operator $A$ satisfies $A^*=A$, so you want to look at e.g. $(TT^*)^*$. 
For eigenvalues, you'll want to look at the expression $\lambda = \langle v,Av\rangle=\dots$ where I've assumed that $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector.

Comment: For any operators $S,T:V \to V$, $ST$ and $TS$ will have the same eigenvalues

Comment: I guess it amounts to the fact that $(A^*)^*=A$ and the definitions.